# Window cannot be moved/unmaximized (alt + drag does not work)

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, fullscreen, maximized

There is exactly 1 program that is having this issue. Every other program is working perfectly fine.

Regardless of how many times I close this program or restart my machine, this windowed application can only appear in full screen. What's worse, it does not respect my show launcher settings. Using Alt + Space I can get the window dropdown to appear, but regardless of whether I click Maximize or Unmaximize, it doesn't change or move a bit. I can move it to another workspace via this menu, but in every workspace it renders the same (full screen, hiding the launcher, cannot be moved with Alt + drag). I have tried disabling / reenabling Unity (no effect) and have window decorations set to off.

The last option is to uninstall and reinstall the program, but I'd prefer to not have to do this. If anyone has any idea, please do share!

Thank you.

Comment: What program is it? Why not try reinstalling it?

Comment: @wjandrea It's mysql-workbench that I installed from dpkg directly. I have conerns (since that program is a peice of shit to begin with) that it'll remove/lose my half dozen remote connection configurations... Would be a realy waste of my time setting that back up